# web scraping data without matched pages using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm Trying to scrape the status from [bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/)

I want to get this table from each page

[image: Table]

this table isn't in specific place in the page \ sometimes there is multiple of it

i want my script to look for the table in the page and if it find 1 return the element tag and ignore the other ones

here is some pages with the table in different places:

[page 1](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Charmander_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

[page 2](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

[page 3](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Eternatus_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

i just want to select the table element and then i will extract the data i need

Answer (score 0):

when working with 'wiki' pages without specific ids or classes, what you really want to do - is to find any type of specific characteristic, which will distinguish focus objects from others.

In your case, if we analyze all three pages, the 'stat table' always has `a` tag, which `href` is always `/wiki/Statistic`.

Therefore, to find this specific table, you have two options:

- find each table, which has `a` tag inside with `href` equals `/wiki/Statistic`
- find parent tag `table` of each link with `href` equals `/wiki/Statistic`

Here is an example of code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

pages = [
    'https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Charmander_(Pokémon)',
    'https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pokémon)',
    'https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Eternatus_(Pokémon)'
]

for page in pages:
    response = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    stat_tables = [table for table in soup.find_all('table') if table.find('a') != None and table.find('a')['href'] == '/wiki/Statistic']
    # OR
    stat_tables = [a.find_parent('table') for a in soup.find_all('a', href = '/wiki/Statistic')]

    for table in stat_tables:
        # Parse table
```

Since you said that you want to just extract the table, I'm leaving parsing part on you :)
However, if you have some question, please, feel free to ask.